# Why is cirrhosis not more common due to sugar consumption?

Tags: liver, fructose, fatty-liver-disease

I saw a 55 year old celebrity died from Cirrhosis. Cirrhosis happens after Steatosis.

According to [StatPearls](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33760536/#:%7E:text=Daily%20consumption%20of%2030%20to,more%20than%2040%20g%2Fday.):

> Daily consumption of 30 to 50 gram of alcohol for over five years can cause alcoholic liver disease. Steatosis can occur in 90% of patients who drink over 60g/day, and cirrhosis occurs in 30% of individuals with long-standing consumption of more than 40 g/day.

Fructose is metabolized the same way as alcohol by the liver. Americans consume way more fructose than alcohol.

So why is there no one dying from Cirrhosis caused by fructose?

Is it just really difficult to die from Cirrhosis and the victims are both heavy drinkers and fructose consumers?  Or is it just a low statistical chance?  Would that make it improbably to suffer from Cirrhosis on a fructose free diet?

Comment: Evidence of research in an attempt to answer your question is required on this site. "Cirrhosis happens after Steatosis" Why? .E.g.how is non-alcoholic fatty liver disease different than cirrhosis? Does that answer your question? If not, why not? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences. You state that no one is dying from cirrhosis caused by fructose” - do you have a source for that?

Comment: Hi chris. No source for that.. However sugar is in everything, coke, ketchup, fast food. Most food sources have sugar because it's used to cause a dopamine response in customers. Many obese people drink 2ltrs of hfcs soda a day, which contains like 108g of fructose. Alcoholics are at 30 percent risk of fatty liver disease from only 30g of alcohol consumption a day, yet many americans have hundreds of grams of fructose a day.  Since so much fructose is incorporated in the food, it would make sense that if it caused Cirrhosis, it would be publicly more known.